# Numpy error: Singular matrix

Tags: python, numpy

What does the error `Numpy error: Matrix is singular` mean specifically (when using the `linalg.solve` function)? I have looked on Google but couldn't find anything that made it clear when this error occurs.

Comment: If you have a singular matrix, then it might indicate that you have some mistake in your matrix filling routine. If your matrix really is singular, then you may get some useful information about it using singular value decomposition. However in this case you need to have a good understanding of linear algebra and numerical computing concepts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A singular matrix is one that is not invertible. This means that the system of equations you are trying to solve does not have a unique solution; `linalg.solve` can't handle this.

You may find that `linalg.lstsq` provides a usable solution.

Comment: By "no unique solution" do you mean it may have multiple solutions?

Comment: @KaliMa That is what I mean.

Comment: @MichaelJBarber Is there a way to get it to return all possible solutions? Is that what linalg.lstsq does?

Comment: @KaliMa When a system of equations is singular, it either has infinitely many solutions, or none - so no, in general you can't retrieve them all. Linalg.lstsq just returns one of those solutions - even if there is none: in that case, it returns the 'best' solution (in a least squares sense); but then, too, there are infinitely many other 'best' solutions. For further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Comment: @RolfBartstra Is there a way to error-trap this? My program nosedives when it hits this singular-matrix error and it'd be nice to just continue my loop instead.

Comment: @KaliMa You can use a `try: ... except: ...` block to catch the error; to deal with the singularity, you have to come up with a solution yourself ... ;-) Or use `lstsq`: that won't crash, and leaves you at least with _one_ solution ...

Answer (score 6):

This function inverts singular matrices as well using `numpy.linalg.lstsq`:

```
def inv(m):
    a, b = m.shape
    if a != b:
        raise ValueError("Only square matrices are invertible.")

    i = np.eye(a, a)
    return np.linalg.lstsq(m, i)[0]
```