# Using Apache Library for OLS Regression : Matrix is singular exception

Tags: java, linear-regression

I am using the Apache Math Library for Java to find the OLS regression for a set of data. However, I will occasionally get the following error : "org.apache.commons.math3.linear.SingularMatrixException: matrix is singular"

The data that the regression is applied to is not always the same set. It is a set generated after traversing a decision tree. Here is one of the sample data sets that produces this exception:

```
    [1.41385, 0.0, 19.58, 1.0, 0.871, 6.129, 96.0, 1.7494, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 321.02, 15.12, 17.0, 
     0.59005, 0.0, 21.89, 0.0, 0.624, 6.372, 97.9, 2.3274, 4.0, 437.0, 21.2, 385.76, 11.12, 23.0, 
     8.24809, 0.0, 18.1, 0.0, 0.713, 7.393, 99.3, 2.4527, 24.0, 666.0, 20.2, 375.87, 16.74, 17.8, 
     2.44953, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 6.402, 95.2, 2.2625, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 330.04, 11.32, 22.3, 
     2.14918, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.871, 5.709, 98.5, 1.6232, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 261.95, 15.79, 19.4, 
     2.3139, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 5.88, 97.3, 2.3887, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 348.13, 12.03, 19.1, 
     2.3139, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 5.88, 97.3, 2.3887, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 348.13, 12.03, 19.1, 
     2.44953, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 6.402, 95.2, 2.2625, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 330.04, 11.32, 22.3, 
     8.24809, 0.0, 18.1, 0.0, 0.713, 7.393, 99.3, 2.4527, 24.0, 666.0, 20.2, 375.87, 16.74, 17.8, 
     2.3139, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 5.88, 97.3, 2.3887, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 348.13, 12.03, 19.1, 
     2.3004, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 6.319, 96.1, 2.1, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 297.09, 11.1, 23.8, 
     5.66637, 0.0, 18.1, 0.0, 0.74, 6.219, 100.0, 2.0048, 24.0, 666.0, 20.2, 395.69, 16.59, 18.4, 
     5.66637, 0.0, 18.1, 0.0, 0.74, 6.219, 100.0, 2.0048, 24.0, 666.0, 20.2, 395.69, 16.59, 18.4, 
     2.3139, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 5.88, 97.3, 2.3887, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 348.13, 12.03, 19.1, 
     2.3139, 0.0, 19.58, 0.0, 0.605, 5.88, 97.3, 2.3887, 5.0, 403.0, 14.7, 348.13, 12.03, 19.1, 
     14.0507, 0.0, 18.1, 0.0, 0.597, 6.657, 100.0, 1.5275, 24.0, 666.0, 20.2, 35.05, 21.22, 17.2]
    nobs: 16 nvars: 13
```

How can I avoid getting this error? Is there a Java solution similar to the python one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795682/numpy-error-singular-matrix).

Answer (score 5):

Today I´ve suffered the same problem with Apache commons-math OLS.
I worked around this issue eliminating rows and columns that are composed only by zeros.
For example, in your case, if you remove the second column, the matrix is non singular and the OLS will work.

I hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the columns of the matrix above are the variables, the one that is identically 0 will lead to this exception.  In order for an ordinary least squares problem to have a unique solution, the independent variables have to be linearly independent (no column can be a linear combination of any subset of the others).  A full column of 0's violates this by itself.  See for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares for more info on what is required to estimate an OLS model.  When the **no linear dependence** condition defined there is not met, a SingularMatrixException results.

To help understand this intuitively, think about what you are asking the algorithm to do.  You want it to get the **best** set of coefficients b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, ..., b<sub>n</sub> so that the model 
y = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + ... + b<sub>n</sub>x<sub>n</sub> 
 fits the data better than any other choice of b<sub>i</sub>.  If x<sub>1</sub> is always 0, it makes no difference what you make b<sub>1</sub> - so there is no unique solution.  Similarly, if say x<sub>1</sub> = 2x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub>, however you decide to choose b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub> and b<sub>3</sub>, there are infinitely other ways you could set them that would give exactly the same values for that part of the model.