# Solve linear equations with multiple variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have some equations with some variables. I want to find the values of those variables. How would I do it?
The equations are like -

a + b = 25,
a + c = 20, b + d = 17, c + d = 12

Now I want to find the value of a, b, c, d.

I have tried using the below code but I am getting an exception.
Code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,1,0,0], [1,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1], [0,0,1,1]])
B = np.array([25, 20, 17, 12])
x = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
print x
```

Exception:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/achilles/Desktop/Desktop/python/nump.py", line 8, in
      
    x = np.linalg.solve(A, B)  
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 375, in 
    solve  
    r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)  
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 90, in 
    _raise_linalgerror_singular  
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")  
    LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

I think this is because I have used '0' (zero) in place of missing variables in the equations. Like in the first equation, 'c' and 'd', are missing, so I used 0 for both of them.
So what could be the solution to find the values of these variables.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: added the exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy error: Singular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795682/numpy-error-singular-matrix)

Comment: @GPhilo, with the help of the above link, the value of x is :  array([ 13.25,  11.75,   6.75,   5.25]), array([], dtype=float64), 3, array([ 2.        ,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  0.        ])).........still could not find the values of variables.

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear. You matrix is singular. Do you know the math behind the solving of such a system ? Singular matrix means the automatic basic method won't work, because there no solution, or an infinity of them.

Comment: and you where right to put `0`s instead of missing variables.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not a code one, it is a maths problem - the reason you get a linear algebra error here is because this is not solvable. if you put your input into wolframalpha you can see this:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2B+b+%3D+25,+a+%2B+c+%3D+20,+b+%2B+d+%3D+17,+c+%2B+d+%3D+12

gives the output `b = 25 - a, c = 20 - a, d = a - 8` which means that although you can find the relative values of your variables, these define a surface of possible solutions (think of your unique solution being a point on a graph where x=1, y=2, this is like saying the solution is anywhere along the line where y = x + 3 --- but ignore that if it doesn't help!)

compare that to the output if your final equation was c + d *+ a* = 12:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2B+b+%3D+25,+a+%2B+c+%3D+20,+b+%2B+d+%3D+17,+c+%2B+d+%2B+a%3D+12

`a = 0, b = 25, c = 20, d = -8`

(by the way, your approach is correct and would work for solvable equations)

which is a single defined solution. The problem therefore is that your equations do not constrain a single solution and so you can't 'solve' them.

Answer (score 1):

Your equations have no unique solution; if you pick a value for one of the variables, you can determine what values the rest have to be.

For example: if a=0, then 0+b=25 and 0+c=20, which leads you to 20+d=12, so d=-8.

Comment: so how could I find the values for a,b,c,d here?

Comment: Values certainly matter (a=b=c=d=0 -- satisfied?). It just have infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of a matrix determines how many solutions you can have.  A positive determinant means one unique solution, a negative determinant means there is no solution, and if

```
np.linalg.det(A)

0.0
```

that means your matrix is "singular", with solutions that lie on a plane, and no unique solution.

Comment: That is false. A nonzero determinant means there is exactly one solution; it doesn't matter whether the determinant is positive or negative. However, a determinant equal to 0 might mean there are an infinity of solutions, or no solutions at all; if the system is `A * X = B` and matrix A is such that `det(A) == 0`, then there might be no solutions or an infinity of solutions depending on B.

Answer (score 0):

```
class equ:  # Creating Class
def equation(self,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2): # Entering Variable in Function
    # x + y = C Write variable in these form, Variable is always +ve , make constant -ve.
    # a = f'{x1}x + {y1}y = {z1}'
    # b = f'{x2}x + {y2}y = {z2}'
    y =(z1*x2 - z2*x1)/(y1*x2 - y2*x1)
    x = (z1 - (y*y1))/x1
    # print(f'First Equation is : {a} \nSecond Equation is : {b}')
    print(f"x = {x} \ny = {y}")
    return x, y    

eq =equ()
# First Equation is : 2x + 2y = 5  
# Second Equation is : 5x + 4y = 14
eq.equation(2,2,5,5,4,14)
```