# Python: Eigenvalue of Specific Number

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector, laplacian

I have a laplacian matrix that I already derived myself.  I want my corresponding eigenvalue to equal zero.  So my equation is `(laplacian matrix) * (eigenvectors) = 0`

I want to find ALL the eigenvectors that make the above equation true.  So essentially I'm looking for all the eigenvectors that when multiplied against laplacian matrix equals 0.

Below is the code I tried:

```
laparray = np.array([[3, -3, 0, 0], [-3, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, -3], [0, 0, -3, 3]])

zeroarray = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

np.linalg.solve(laparray, zeroarray)
```

I get the following error:

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I solve for all the eigenvectors?

Comment: Your matrix is clearly singular: the first and second rows sum to a zero vector, and similarly the third and fourth rows. In such cases, the matrix is not invertible (obviously!) and that is not something `np.linalg.solve` understands. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795682/numpy-error-singular-matrix) for some details if you insist on some sort of numerical result nonetheless.

Comment: I see ... if I want my laplacian matrix dot product my vector to equal vector of 0 what is the function to do that?